# No package systemd available on Amazon linux EC2

Tags: linux, centos, aws, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS Linux machine to host Web API application. I need to make my application keep on run, so that i need **systemd** has to be installed on my linux machine.I tried **sudo yum install systemd** but it gives **No package systemd available.**

My AWS system details are given below,

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Is there any option to manually install **systemd** to my linux system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use Amazon Linux 2 for systemd, where it is installed by default. Amazon Linux 1 is EOL at the end of the year.

Comment: I don't know which version i am using it. How can i identify it?

Comment: To identify 1 vs 2, run `rpm -E %{rhel}` (for Amazon Linux 1, this will give `6` as it's based on RHEL 6, while for Amazon Linux 2, this will give `7` as it's based on RHEL 7).

Comment: How can you not know which version you are using?  _You put the version number in your question_, alongside the URL of a home page for Amazon Linux AMI whose second sentence tells you that Amazon Linux 2 is an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to make my application keep on run, so that i need systemd has to be installed on my linux machine

As others have noted, `systemd` is not available for your version of Amazon Linux. Fortunately, there are other tools than `systemd` that solve your problem; I suggest looking at `cron`. You might take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305963/how-to-setup-cron-job-on-amazon-linux-ami) for how to set a program or script to run on reboot on an Amazon Linux box. Alternatively, there's always the [cron man page, which sould also be on your machine](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html).

Comment: Thank you for your information, i choose Amazon Linux 2 version, now my problem had been resolved